# Callling from either of two devices connected via Multipeer connectivity

Tags: ios, call, multipeer-connectivity

when two devices are connected via Multipeer connectivity,i want tp make call either of the two phones to third phone.

Is it possible?
For Ex. iphone1 and iPhone 2 are connected using multipeer 
i want to make a call to iPhone 3 by using iPhone 1 through iPhone 2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, it is not possible.

Long answer: You can send the audio via multipeer to the second iPhone and use it's connection to send the audio as data over the internet, but you can't inject that audio to a phone call due to the app's sandbox restrictions. Apple is probably doing something like this with iOS8 and Yosemite, where you can receive calls to your phone in your mac, so you probably could do it if you jailbreak.